# Как быстро отдать много картинок

Tags: nginx

Есть задача по локальной сети быстро отдать + отрисовать динамичную страничку со 100+ изображений по 45-50кб каждая (галерея). Поднята связка nginx + php5-fpm, но на загрузку всей графики уходит чуть меньше минуты.

Железка мощная, но сейчас работает почти в холостую, и хотелось бы выжать из неё как можно больше. Как выправить конфиг, чтобы сервер летал и соответственно жрал ресурсы нещадно?

У меня НЕТ опыта администрирования нагруженных проектов и разгона серверного софта, почти нуб в этом.

Comment: да какая разница что у вас железо мощное, если пропускная способность сети низкая и скорость работы HDD очень низкая сама посебе.
 ставьте ssd и тяните гигабитную сетку, тогда я скажу что у вас мощное железо

Answer (score 1):

Помимо настроек кэширования и сжатия статики в nginx, следует настроить параметр передачи сохранения данных в кэш броузера. В первый раз будет длительная загрузка, зато потом - из кэша браузера.
Изначально должны юзеру предоставляться превьюхи - по его команде - полноразмерный файл. Может следует переделать страницу галереи? Превьюхи весят меньше, за счет этого увеличим скорость. Незначительно играет роль и формат файлов для превьюх.
Однако и менее минуты уже красиво для 100+ фоток!